# Joning tables after group by on one table using T SQL/ LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, group-by

I have two tables:

- db.EmployeeReason
- db.employee

with following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Reason](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdEmployee] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdReason] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AverageServiceTime] [time](0) NULL,
    [Skillset] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee_Reason] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Reason]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Reason_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([IdEmployee])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Id])
GO
```

where as the employee table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [IdLocation] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [IsArchived] [bit] NULL,
    [IdAssignedLocation] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdQueue] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdPosition] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to group `employee_reason` by `idreason` and then `join` with employee using `Employee_Reason.idemployee` and `employee.id` like this:

```
List<SelfServeReason> skillsetReasons = 
    from reason in db.EmployeeReason 
    group reason by IdReason into reasonGroup 
    join employee in scheduleEmployees on reasonGroup.IdEmployee equals employee.Id 
    select new skillsetReason
    {
        id = reasonGroup.Id, 
        description = reasonGroup.Description, 
        estimatedWaitTime = min(employee.NextAvailableTime) – ConvertToCST(DateTime.Now)
    };
```

I have written it like this:

```
select MAX(er.Id) 
from Employee_Reason er join Employee e on er.IdEmployee = e.id 
group by er.IdReason
```

but not sure how to group `employee_reasons` and then `join` this group with `idempoyee`.

The linq is not correct, it is just pseudocode, if someone can suggest wha will be correct linq that is helpful as well.

Can you please suggest the solution?

Comment: You specified the collumn you want to group by, but not the columns you want to select. Is it the same ones that are on that linq query?

Comment: @GabrielRainha yes the same ones in linq

Comment: also the linq is not correct, it is just pseudocode, if someone can suggest wha will be correct linq that is helpful as well.

Comment: But there is no NextAvailableTime column on Employee table, and you are querying that column on the linq.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a SQL query simmilar to that linq query, then you could do:

```
select er.IdReason, MIN(e.NextAvailableTime) - GETDATE()
from Employee_Reason er 
inner join Employee e on er.IdEmployee = e.id 
group by er.IdReason
```

Also, the correct linq would look like this:

```
var now = ConvertToCST(DateTime.Now);
List<SelfServeReason> skillsetReasons = (
    from employee in scheduleEmployees
    join reason in db.EmployeeReason on employee.Id equals reason.IdEmployee
    group employee by reason.IdReason into reasonGroup
    select new SelfServeReason
    {
        Id = reasonGroup.Key,
        EstimatedWaitTime = reasonGroup.Min(p => p.NextAvailableTime).Subtract(now),
    }).ToList();
```

Just bear in mind that I excluded the selection of Description from the queries, as you provided no such column on any table nor is there a table like Reason with that column on it.
Also, the tables you provided have no such columns as Employee.NextAvailableTime, so I'm assuming you forgot to put them there, seeing that it on your linq query.
And least, you provided no spec for that SelfServeReason class, so I'll just go on with filling it with the columns I know your model have.
If that's not the case, please expand your question with this adjustments and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: what if we want to write same sql in linq. Remember the linq i wrote is just pseudo code not actual linq

Comment: Then you better specify exactly what you want to select from that query. Mine will do almost the same thing as the linq one, except It wont subtract the current date from the NestAvailableTime.

Comment: @AsifHameed Just included the linq query and improved the answer. Check it out.